# Django - choice set, but no drop down in form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I would like to have a choice set in my model for template and validation.

However, in the model.form for that model I want to have just an integer field.

How can I change the widget in order to just get a InputField?

I tried to change the widget to forms.Model, but that did not seem to work. I get a error:

```
'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

forms.py:

```
class KombiPublikationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = KombiPublikation
        #fields = []
        exclude = ['pub_sprache']
        widgets = {
            'monat': forms.IntegerField(), # does not work
        }
```

model.py:

```
MONTH = (
    (1, 'Januar'),
    (2, 'Februar'),
    (3, 'März'),
    (4, 'April'),
    (5, 'Mai'),
    (6, 'Juni'),
    (7, 'Juli'),
    (8, 'August'),
    (9, 'September'),
    (10, 'Oktober'),
    (11, 'November'),
    (12, 'Dezember'),
)

class KombiPublikation(models.Model):
    [...]
    monat = models.IntegerField(choices=MONTH)
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can use "ChoiceField" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - NumberInput() is the right widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.utils.dates import MONTHS

choices=MONTHS.items()
```